# django 2.2 + Strictness Behaviour + django-filter 2.x

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter, django-filters

I have the django 1.11 code as below and we are using django-filter==1.0 library for filters.

and below is the code according to django 1.11

**Models:**

```
class BaseItem(models.Model):

    CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (STATUS_INACTIVE, 'Inactive'),
    )

class Item(BaseItem):
    name = models.CharField(null=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(null=False)
```

**Filter**

```
class ItemFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    status = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Item.CHOICES, widget=CSVWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['symbol']
        strict = STRICTNESS.RAISE_VALIDATION_ERROR
```

**Viewset**

```
class ItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    queryset = Item.objects.all()

    filterset_class = ItemFilterSet


    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        try:
            return super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        except ValidationError as e:
            if 'symbol' in e.error_dict:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(detail=e.message_dict)
            raise e
```

But in Django 2.2 version we have used django-filter==2.0 library, but in this library, this strictness has been moved to view as per below link.

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/migration.html#filterset-strictness-handling-moved-to-view-788

django-filter other github link

https://github.com/stephenfin/django-filter/commit/552c35ac45b965c2d68e97f9cfdeef940f17d6ea

So my question is,  according to django-filter 2.0 and django 2.2 , in the view, how to handle strictness behaviour in django 2.2 ?